# Как работает зеленая галочка, у ответа на stackoverflow?

Tags: поддержка

> [image: галочка]

В какой момент появляется эта галочка?
Когда ТС подтверждает что ответ ему помог или может голосованием?

Comment: Когда ТС подтверждает

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Больше на вредительство похоже, чем на вопрос по незнанию.

Comment: @Regent не понял вас. Поясните?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, эм.. до переноса там ответы были...

Comment: @D-side я судил по качеству ответов, один из которых принадлежал ТС, а также по "новоиспеченности" обоих аккаунтов, поучаствовавших в вопросе и ответах. После переноса на Мету и удаления тех ответов вопрос выглядит прилично.

Comment: @Qwertiy это те два сомнительного качества?

Comment: @Regent, ну второй-то совсем, а один относительно съедобный был...

Answer (score 3):

> Когда участник получает хороший ответ на свой вопрос, он может отметить его как верный – «принять». После принятия ответа слева от него появляется галочка зелёного цвета.

Подробный ответ есть в [справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).